# Reset CMOS/BIOS

Tags: bios, reset, cmos

I've got an old Fusitsu Esprimo Q1510. The BIOS is corrupted, so I need to reset it.

I've read the manuals on the Fujitsu website, but I can't find any information on how to do this.

How do I fix it?

Comment: Pull out the battery on your motherboard, wait five minutes, and then put it back in. Your bios should then be reset.

Comment: @AidenGrossman Already tried that, didn't work.

Comment: If the bios is corrupt then pulling the battery can't correct the corruption.  Pulling the battery resets the bios configuration it doesn't magically restore the bios from corruption.  Typically the hardware has to have a backup bios to do what you want which your hardware does not have

Comment: @Ramhound Does that mean that I can't restore it?

Comment: That's exactly what it means.

Comment: Pulling out the battery still worth a try. Did you unplugged all other power sources during the test (power cord and eventually the battery)?

Comment: @A.Loiseau I unplugged everything.

Comment: Pull the CMOS battery (not referring to the main battery) and leave it overnight... if you still can't access it properly, then this likely needs to be flashed with a eeprom programmer or have the bios chip replaced (if it's possible on this device). BTW, if you are trying to clear a BIOS password, none of these methods will work, that information is stored in a completely different secure section.

Comment: @acejavelin I need to reset it because when I start it, the fans starts spinning, but nothing else happens.

Comment: That doesn't sound like a anything you can 'clear', that sounds like a bad mainboard.